# Populate dropdown list with selected value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Only the selected Brand is displayed when I wish to modify the form. All Brands will be loaded, however only the chosen Brand will be shown.

Part: 1

```
ViewData["ddlBrand"] = new SelectList(_iCommon.LoadddlBrand(), "GID", "Name");
```

Part: 2

```
ViewData["ddlBrand"] = new SelectList(_iCommon.LoadddlBrandByGID(vm.BrandGID), "GID", "Name");
return PartialView("_Edit", vm);
```

.chtml

```
<div class="form-group row">
<label asp-for="BrandGID" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"></label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
<select asp-for="BrandGID" asp-items="@ViewBag.ddlBrand" id="BrandGID" class="form-control" style="width:100%;">
<option disabled selected>--- SELECT ---</option>
</select>
<span asp-validation-for="BrandGID" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How does your `SelectList` and Model look like? I noticed that you bind the `BrandGID` for the select option, does this mean that the Value(GID) you set in the `SelectList` is equal to the `BrandGID`? This way when you edit the form the select should show up as the select option you selected for `BrandGID`.

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?